# Как удалить список приложений в пуске windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу их убрать. Как это сделать?

Comment: ПКМ -> Удалить?

Answer (score 1):

Параметры -> Персонализация -> Пуск -> Показать список приложений в меню "Пуск"

---

[image: Параметры -> Персонализация]

---

[image: Пуск -> Показать список приложений в меню "Пуск"]